# Showing different divs based on radio button select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.choose_level input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
    if ($('input[name=level1]:checked').val()) {           
        $('.choose_level').addClass('hidden');
        $('.choose_style').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else if ($('input[name=level1b]]:checked').val()) {           
        $('.choose_level').addClass('hidden');
        $('.choose_layout').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    });
```

I have 3 different Divs. The first div has two radion buttons. If the user selects radio(name=level1), #choose_style displays. If they select radio(name=level1b), #choose_layout displays. Right now the first part works but the second radio does not.

Comment: Is it `#choose_layout` or `.choose_layout`? The same for the `choose_style`.

Comment: Why are you checking it if has a value? Maybe you should post your HTML as well, as this makes little sense

Comment: Why not use .toggle() instead of assigning classes to show/hide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `]`

```
$('input[name=level1b]]:checked')
                      ^
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that. I was so sure that I had the idea right, and was so confused when it didn't work.

Comment: So another ? for you... in .choose_style I have 4 check boxes. I want my button with .hidden to display if any of the checkboxes are checked. if ($('.homestyle').is(':checked'))
  $('.homes').removeClass('hidden'); doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user3032873 - you might want to open a new question for that with the valid HTML & your jquery code associated with it.